# android ndk project having error when loading the library

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

i am very new to the android ndk and opencv
but i have already run some samples/tutorials of opencv projects in Eclipse
 therefore the opencv library should not be a problem

[Here i want to run this camera project from github, i think it should work](https://github.com/miladm/panorama-HDR-opencv)

After I downloaded it and import it into the Eclipse,
I encountered a problem :

When I run it it stops and finishes because the library cannot be loaded in the CameraActivity.

```
           ->     System.loadLibrary("PanoHDR");
```

I have tried to search the web for solutions but they either didn't work or I didn't understand them.

Do I need to do something like "ndk-build" at somewhere to make it work?

Could someone please help me? I cannot find any solution.

here is the default android.mk

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

 include $(CLEAR_VARS)

 # Tegra optimized OpenCV.mk
 include /Users/milmil/Documents/NVPACK/OpenCV-2.4.5-Tegra-sdk-r2/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV-tegra3.mk

 # Linker
 LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog

 # Our module sources
 LOCAL_MODULE    := PanoHDR
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := PanoHDR.cpp Panorama.cpp HDR.cpp NativeLogging.cpp

 include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

when i try to use ndk-build in cmd in the main dir of the project
it fails

```
jni/Android.mk:6: /sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV-tegra3'.  Stop.
```

and it should be caused by this line in the Andriod.mk

```
include /Users/milmil/Documents/NVPACK/OpenCV-2.4.5-Tegra-sdk-r2/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV-tegra3.mk
```

I try to use the path of my opencv sdk

```
include /Android/OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

and it returns this in the cmd

```
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:PanoHDR: non-system libraries in linker flag
s: -lopencv_java3
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_S
TATIC_LIBRARIES
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependenc
ies of the
Android NDK:     current module
[armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ thumb": "PanoHDR <= PanoHDR.cpp"
The system cannot find the path specified.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/PanoHDR/PanoHDR.o] Error 1
```

Thank you

=========================================================================

```
WARNING:jni/Android.mk:PanoHDR: non-system libraries in linker flag
s: -lopencv_java3
```

the above problem is solved by adding `"OPENCV_LIB_TYPE=STATIC"` in the android.mk, but still has this error "

```
[armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ thumb": "PanoHDR <= PanoHDR.cpp"
The system cannot find the path specified.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/PanoHDR/PanoHDR.o] Error 1"
```

Comment: Using the NDK is difficult and a solid understanding of both C++ and Java/Android is pretty much required. Using a C++ library in Android is not as easy as just dropping in the library and then coding Android. You have to follow very specific steps using an ndk-build system and bridge files that translate the C++ code over to Java. I would suggest you follow Google's step-by-step tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html -- and then ask questions along the way as you get stuck.

Comment: could someone tell me the procedure on how to load a android ndk project please, thank you .